# Higher Order Component renders the wrapped element as a 'tag ' string

Tags: reactjs

Learning react I am trying to write a higher order component to add a delete button on an item. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here:

```
const deletableItem = WrappedComponent => {
  const DeletableItemWrapper = class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
          <button onClick={this.props.onDelete}>delete</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  DeletableItemWrapper.propTypes = {
    onDelete: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  DeletableItemWrapper.displayName = 
    'DeletableItemWrapper_' +WrappedComponent.displayName
  return DeletableItemWrapper
}
```

I am testing it this way:

```
 describe('deletableItem', () => {
   it('should contains dumb', () => {
     const onDelete = sinon.spy()
     const DumbComponent = () => <div>dumb</div>
     const Item = deletableItem(DumbComponent)
     const wrapper = shallow(<Item onDelete={onDelete} />)
     expect(wrapper.text()).to.contains('dumb')
   })
})
```

The test gives me:

```
AssertionError: expected '<DumbComponent />delete' to include 'dumb'
```

So it look like the HOC is not rendering the 'wrapped element' but just the tag as a string. What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was confused by another error when testing in browser. So it seems the problem is that it is not working when shallow rendering but everything is fine when rendering in the browser. Then I will not test anymore the decorated component, but in this case only the fact that the HOC adds a delete button.

[How to test decorated React component with shallow rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459720/how-to-test-decorated-react-component-with-shallow-rendering?rq=1)